# No working Java was detected on IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, java

**Problem**: Internet Explorer 9 is not detecting Java

**IE Version**: 9.0.8112.16421

**Requirement**: Need to open applet on IE browser

### Problem description

In one client system, we are facing issue in opening a applet. When I checked then I found Java is not detecting in browser.

But when I checked the Java control panel then I found JRE1.6 is installed in the system.

### Already tried

After that I tried to search some article related to the problem, that jdk1.6.0_26 is installed on system but still it is not detectable on browser.

I followed the link but it's solution could be resolved the issue.
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

We are stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention OS. It also depend upon OS.

If it is Windows 64 bit OS, then It would have IE 64(x64) bit and IE 32(x86) bit.

**If it is x64 bit then It would have requirement of 64 bit jre.** . For launching the applet.

**If it is x86 bit then It would have requirement of 32 bit jre.**. For launching the applet.

Please follow this and revert.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading, but correct. The truth is that x64 windows runs a by x32 IE version by default. To enable x64 IE, you must adjust IE advanced settings and enable UAC. If you have not done this, then install the x32 Java JRE.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things that may be happening:

1. If you installed IE9 after Java, the Java plugin may not be installed.  Try running the Java installer again while IE9 is closed.
2. The JDK you have is really out of date and may be blocked by IE9 because of that.  Try installing the latest JRE [here](http://www.java.com/en/).

Comment: First option I have already followed. Second can be the reason but I have tried with JDK1.7 after closing IE. After that I restarted but still It was same.

Comment: Have you tried to install just the JRE?  The JDK usually comes with a JRE but I'm not sure if it includes the needed plugins.

Comment: Should I go for this http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the add-on page? Have a look, and be sure to select "All" from "View" or "show" on the left, and not only "Loaded" add-ons. You can find this dialog in the extras, press and hold Alt, watch out for "Manage Add-Ons", not sure how it is called in your local. Every add-on in the list can be deactivated, as well as you might find out, that the one that you think of is installed is missing.

The Java setup works quite well if you need an Ask Toolbar. It fails numerous times if you are using the browser, running an instance of the Runtime Environment, or one million other "good reasons" to fail to add an add on on your browser, and it is completely irrelevant which browser you use - the setup will find a way to fail.

Answer (score -2):

Under tools there is a check box for ActiveX Filtering. **Make sure this is unchecked**- that caused me no end of headaches.  It is a bad idea to have two switches that do the same thing in software.

You can do the same thing using the settings in Internet Options/security/custom level but the two switches don't talk to each other.